# Is horizontal align not considered an X position constraint in Xcode storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and I'm trying to figure out storyboard constraints. I think I got the hang of it, but one problem that keeps appearing still troubles me. I have a simple title that is supposed to be horizontally centered. So I use Editor -> Align -> Horizontally in Container. Visually, this does exactly what I want it to do. But there is a yellow warning that says that I need an X position constraint. Why isn't the center considered a constraint?

If I do put an X position constraint, then my title will no longer be horizontally centered across different screen sizes. What do I do?

The full error message is "Need constraints for: X position"

[image]

Comment: Make sure the title is inside a view that has its x position constrained - either set an explicit `x` and `width`, or have `leading` and `trailing`.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Is the "Horizontally in Container" constraint the only constraint you added to your view?

Comment: @Sweeper My current file just has a button at the top left (which is fully constrained and posses no problems) and then the aforementioned text title which is constrained a few pixels below the button. Nothing else is on the page.

Comment: @aheze Do I need to put it inside a view? Is there a specific reason why I am not able to solve the problem without using a view?

Comment: Oh wait, you did this through the "Editor" menu! That doesn't actually add any constraints. Can you show a screenshot of your storyboard, showing the "yellow warning"?

Comment: @Sweeper I was under the impression that the "editor" method was the only way to center things. Is there another (without actual coding)? I can't attach a screenshot, but the full message reads "Need constraints for: X position" with a small red dot (It used to be a yellow triangle, but it changed to red after I put my title in a View container as suggested by @aheze)

Comment: @Sweeper Edit my question to add what? The error message?

Comment: Why can't you attach a screenshot? You see, I can show you how to add a "horizontally in container" constraint, but that still won't make the error disappear if you don't have enough other constraints. This is why I asked for a storyboard screenshot, so I can reproduce the error on my machine, and tell you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: @Sweeper , ok, I just added an image to the original post. Hopefully that can help clear things up. The page is only the button and title.

Answer (score 0):

The "Align -> Horizontally in Container" menu item in the Editor menu doesn't actually add any constraints. It *only* aligns your view.

To add a "horizontally in container" constraint, use this button in the bottom right:

[image]

Note that a "horizontally in container" constraint on its own doesn't make the view's X position unambiguous, because it only constraints the view's *center X*, whereas "X position" refers to the x coordinate of the leftmost place on the view. The width of the view also needs to be unambiguous, for the X position to be unambiguous. You seem to have added a width constraint to the label, so that's fine. If you didn't, it's fine too, because a label's width can be determined by its content.

You also don't need to put the label inside of another container view (you seem to have misunderstood [aheze's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278720/is-horizontal-align-not-considered-an-x-position-constraint-in-xcode-storyboard?noredirect=1#comment122448136_69278720)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Do you happen to know why the Editor horizontal align does not actually align anything? It seems weird for it to be called align but doesn't actually give constraints.

Comment: @GabrieleScottodiVettimo it doesn’t seem weird to me at all… All it says is “align”, not “add alignment constraints”… also note that this is a feature available in many UI editors, from my experience.